# Is it possible to manually add addtional codecs to VLC Media Player for a portable install?

Tags: windows, video, vlc-media-player, codec, portable

I have two DLL files and one OCX file for a proprietary codec format to play some specific videos encoded with it.  While I have an "installer" for it that works fine to register the codec for the entire PC, I want to know if it's possible to just manually add the codecs to a portable VLC install on a USB stick so I don't have to install codecs on other machines or have admin access to them.

Is there just a folder I can drop these that VLC will automatically utilize?
A config file I need to modify?
Do I have to recompile VLC to accommodate additional codecs?
Are there any video applications that can have codecs added like this?

Also, yes, I can re-encode the video files but I'd rather have the originals and just bring the codec with me.

Comment: What video codec is it? because vlc supports a pretty massive amount of codecs including vp9 and h265

Comment: They're proprietary codecs from a CCTV system.  AVI files with ADV1 or ZJPG as the codec.

Answer (score 0):

Being a DLL file only means it can be used as a shared library on Windows not that any particular program will have any use for them. Most likely the DLLs are DirectShow filters which is baked into Windows. VLC can use DirectShow to play back media but only through DirectShow and the libraries registered for it requiring an "install" or at least registry edits to Windows.